# Changed username - Could not update ICE authority file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, terminal, users

I tried to change my username by creating another admin account, restarting, then logging into that new account.  Then, I entered the following command:

```
sudo usermod -l NewUserName -d /home/NewUserName -m OldUserName
```

However, when I logged out of my temporary account and tried to log back into my main account, there was a black screen with a small popup box that read:

> Could not update ICE authority file /home/NewUserName/ ICE authority.

What might be causing this and how can I successfully change my username?

Comment: Does `NewUserName` own `/home/NewUserName`?

Comment: I do not know (new to linux)  how would I check?

Comment: From a terminal, `ls -ld /home/NewUserName` - you might also want to do `ls -l /home/NewUserName/{.ICE,.X}authority`